# AVR ATmega328p-pu operating circuit?

Tags: avr, arduino-micro

I used to work with PIC micro-controller so i know what it needs to work from operating circuit to crystal oscillators needed and other components to power it up , my question here where can i find the operating circuit for ATmega32p-pu and other AVR models . or all i need to do is to give it +5v and gnd and it will work ?

Comment: Just 5v, crystal (with caps), and probably a pull-up on the reset pin. Just make sure you connect all the 5v pins and all ground pins. PS you can skip the crystal if you use the internal RC oscillator. PPS blank chips have [their fuses](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc) set, so it runs at 1mHz from the internal oscillator. With some programmers you need to select a slower speed, to program the AVR running at only 1mHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [this](http://arduino.cc/en/main/standalone) I think? How to set up an Arduino on a breadboard.

Comment: thanks man but not exactly i don't need the complete functions of arduino i just want to power up and make the chip work no more no less

Comment: So, just take the bits you need from that page - it  is quite modular.